# Issuing auto signed certificate - IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, https, ssl-certificate

I issued a self signed certificate on IIS 7.5, and it is working correctly if i access my website through my computer.
However, if i access the website from another computer, i get an warning saying the certificate was issued to another address.

Is this because the certificate was issued to localhost instead of the actual IP?
Or this doesn't make any sense?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting is normal, assuming you do not have anything in your certificate aside from 'localhost' to identify the owner.

Your browser is performing a name check, and looking to validate the certificate that is presented with the URL you typed in. Typically, the common name of a certificate matches the hostname/DNS name of the machine. Alternatively, there can be information inside of the Subject Alt Name (SAN) extension of your certificate. There, you could specify multiple DNS names or IPAddress fields that identify your server in addition to the CN.

If you are simply performing internal testing, I would not be terribly worried about the warning you are receiving. Just keep all of this in mind when you move to production. Also, having your CA being self-signed, you may also receive trust warnings, unless you manually import your self-signed CA certificate into the trust store of the browser you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I am having however trouble accessing the page through Firefox 4, even though i try to workaround the security exception. I try to add the exception and it won't let me. Besides, this won't be for internal testing but for deployment on a server. It will be used only by trusted people. Is there any way to make the connection secure without these warnings? (Because the people that will be using this (people with few knowledge of computers) could find the warnings to be a bit scary)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you: [Self signed certificates on IIS 7](http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/). At the end of the article, in the section named **"Adding the Certificate to Trusted Root Certificate Authorities"**, an alternative solution is shown, but it implies importing the certificate in the client machine, so that could be a huge disadvantage. However, it is a solution if you can't register the certificate on a Certificate Authority, an you have access to the client machine.